# controling the size of the cloth

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation

I wanted to make my cloth and rig smaller . 
Is there a way to change the scale in the bake?
I tried baking it after i scale the shirt down but the shirt suddenly go into a weird shape.
Why does the cloth work well when my collision objects is big but went into a weird shape when it was scaled down? Is it the settings?
Here is the file 
http://www.mediafire.com/download/ytao6s7wqo3vpgo/robin+ninja+run.blend

Comment: Can you show it with pictures or explain more specific? I unbaked my cloth , scaled down the collision objects with the cloth , and ctrl+a scale , but my clothes still went out of shape.

Comment: Ohh , i double checked again and found that my cloth was setted to preset after i scaled it . I changed it back to leather and it fix everything . Thankyou.